# TKPROF usage as a developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, database-administration

If I'm a developer, how can I use the SQL Trace and TKPROF without any needs of extra privileges or help from the DBAs? Because to use it, I need to have the read/write privilege to a folder inside of the database directory. Or is there a different way?

So if I'm just an ordinary developer, can use that **by my own user** without any help or extra privilege?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL trace evaluates cost of every statement executed in the session. This includes all the recursive SQL issued by the compiler and the optimiser to parse the query and devise the most efficient access path. Which means it is considered an overhead against normal SQL, and consequently enabling it requires privileged access. You need your DBA to grant you the required privileges as a one-off exercise or to enable Trace for you every time you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation @APC. You are great on your each help. Regards.

Comment: @oramas If you have Enterprise Edition with the diagnostics and tuning pack options then you don't need tracing anymore.  Active Session History data is easily accessible through available through the data dictionary, like in V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY.  If you're stuck on Standard Edition, look into a utility to replicate ASH, such as Simulated-ASH.  Performance tuning is *so* much easier when you can do it entirely with SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your help @John Heller. Best Regards.